# How to prompt Llama2 for text classification?

Tags: prompt-design, llm, llama-2

Here is my script:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM   

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")

prompt = """
A message can be classified as one of the following categories: book, cancel, change.

Based on these categories, classify this message:
I would like to cancel my booking and ask for a refund.
"""

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
outputs = model.generate(input_ids, max_new_tokens=200)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))
```

Here is the output:

```
<s> 
A message can be classified as one of the following categories: book, cancel, change.

Based on these categories, classify this message:
I would like to cancel my booking and ask for a refund.

Please select one of the following options:

book
cancel
change</s>
```

I would like to know how to design a prompt so that Llama-2 can give me "cancel" as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can just add category examples, the more the merrier. 'tis like so:

```
prompt = """
A message can be classified as one of the following categories: book, cancel, change.

Examples:
- Book: "I would like to book a room for two nights."
- Cancel: "Please cancel my reservation and refund the payment."
- Change: "I need to change the dates of my booking to next week."

Based on these categories, classify this message:
"I would like to cancel my booking and ask for a refund."
"""
```

make the examples fine-tuned to your business or w/e.